# Developing new Option type for Product in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

I want to code a new option type for products in OpenCart, for example lets say: there is already an option for checkbox (Catelog->Options->insert and select checkbox from 'Type' Dropdown). The default checkbox has three entry fields 1. Option Value Name' 2. Image 3. Sort Order. Now if I want to create a new checkbox with different entry options like a checkbox with a category or product selection option. How to deal with such a situation. At Opencart's Official documentation http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Developer+guide : that explains only how to create a module which has its own individual layout(.tpl) but in my case I don't need to provide additional layout in admin area for this sort of module, I just need to hookup my code in such a way that it displays newly added option with existing options listed under Catelog->Options->insert and 'Type'. Any help or clue will be appreciated from you guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you want to add a new option type and add option values to it? Your question seems to be a little bit confusing!

Comment: No I want to create a completely new option(like checkbox or select) which will work in the same way as default options work, but that will accept different parameters(entry values).

Comment: You meant you want to add a new option to the default 12 options provided by opencart? Checkbox 
 Color
 Date  
 Date & Time 
 Delivery Date  
 File  
 Radio 
 Select 
 Size  
 Text  
 Textarea  
 Time

Comment: And what is so complicated on copying and customizing the code of one of the present options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `admin/view/template/catalog/option_form.tpl`

```
 <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_type; ?></td>
        <td><select name="type">
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $text_choose; ?>">
            <?php if ($type == 'select') { ?>
            <option value="select" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="select"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'radio') { ?>
            <option value="radio" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_radio; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="radio"><?php echo $text_radio; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'checkbox') { ?>
            <option value="checkbox" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_checkbox; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="checkbox"><?php echo $text_checkbox; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'image') { ?>
            <option value="image" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_image; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="image"><?php echo $text_image; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $text_input; ?>">
            <?php if ($type == 'text') { ?>
            <option value="text" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_text; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="text"><?php echo $text_text; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'textarea') { ?>
            <option value="textarea" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_textarea; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="textarea"><?php echo $text_textarea; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $text_file; ?>">
            <?php if ($type == 'file') { ?>
            <option value="file" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_file; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="file"><?php echo $text_file; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $text_date; ?>">
            <?php if ($type == 'date') { ?>
            <option value="date" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_date; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="date"><?php echo $text_date; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'time') { ?>
            <option value="time" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_time; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="time"><?php echo $text_time; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'datetime') { ?>
            <option value="datetime" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_datetime; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="datetime"><?php echo $text_datetime; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </optgroup>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
```

You can see that the option types are hardcoded. Just edit it or use vqmod(**[Opencart Vqmod Tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)**) to add your new option type.

Have a nice day!!

Comment: you are still confused dear. I need to create new option in 'Type' dropdown for example 'checkbox with related product' and that option must be available in that list to select. I'm asking for programming level not at administration level.